# Prove that $f : \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined as $f(m, n) = 2n - 4m$ is not injective

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I know that if this function is injective, then for $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$ in the set $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, then $f(a, b) = f(c, d)$ implies that $a = c \wedge b = d$:

$f(a, b) = f(c, d)$

$2b - 4a = 2d - 4c$

$b - 2a = d - 2c$

And now I'm stuck as to how I should proceed, as there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to prove from this that $a$ must equal $c$ and that $b$ must equal $d$. I tried taking the contrapositive--that is, that if $a \ne c \vee b \ne d$, then $f(a, b) \ne f(c, d)$, but that's even worse.

Comment: One counterexample is enough. Try to find non-zero solutions to $f(m,n)=f(0,0)\,$ for example.

Comment: just see that $f(0,0)=f(1,2)=0$

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake. The approach I've taken here is for proving injectivity, whereas proving non-injectivity requires using a counterexample. Any way one can arrive at an intuitive guess as opposed to randomly trying values? I'm not too good at guessing :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $f(m+k, n+2k) = f(m,n)$ for $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Interesting, I just expanded that myself, and it does work. Intuitively, I feel it has something to do with 4 being 2 greater than 2, but I don't quite understand why this works :(

Comment: @AleksandrH Just solve the equation $f(m+k, n+x)=f(m,n)$ for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly not injective. Let's take $(-2,-1), (2,1)$ These are two different couples going to $0$, so the Kernel is not trivial.